# How do I change the name that appears when sending email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail address and in the main welcome screen, after I log out, it says "Phil Test" which is a name I put in somewhere 'cos I don't want to put my surname in.

But when I send email, my surname (not test) goes in the email at the destination. I don't want that happening.

So there must be two settings for first and last name.

Where is the other one?

I see in my sent folder it puts my surname in there

[image: Google log in dialog]

[image: screen shot from Gmail showing name]

Comment: @pnuts the title of that one sounds like a duplicate, but the contents of that question is that guy was saying he changed it and it didn't work and his answer was there was a delay.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two places for changing the name

## **THE WRONG PLACE**

The place that affects the welcome screen (but not the email, not the from header!) is

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Above, won't change the information in the FROM HEADER, of the email, so won't change the name the person receiving it sees, (or the name you see in your sent folder)

## THE RIGHT PLACE

Below, would change that FROM Header.. which is what effects what the person receiving sees.

The Gear icon, has a settings option (this is different from accounts-settings)

Here is the gear-settings option!

[image]

[image]

You get to this screen and change the name here. That will affect the From header. It was set to the surname Baroni but you could change it to something else

[image]

Comment: How to do that on android? Even if I tell google chrome to show normal version of the website it still shows the mobile version and I can't find these settings.

Comment: @Barteks2x  there is an android stackexchange site, but also this forum has lots of knowledgeable people and may help http://forums.androidcentral.com/   and if you already solved it you can write where the option is